# When I try to install Ubuntu, the screen res is too low to use the installer

Tags: 13.04, grub2, nvidia, resolution, nomodeset

I have an Acer Aspire V3 with 8gb RAM, 1tb HDD, nVidia GeForce 650m 2gb graphics, 17.3" screen with 1600x900 res. When I use GRUB I cant boot it without nomodeset. When I get to the graphical installer, the screen resolution is 640 x 480 and i cant change it. The buttons are too far down to be able to press them. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Holding down the Super key will let you drag the installer windows upwards enabling you to use the buttons.

Comment: Useful answer, thank you. Saves me asking the same question.

Comment: When i got to the partition part I couldn't get any further because I couldn't press the continue button.

Comment: I know the problem. It should be the Meta key not the Super Key.